# What size errorbars on contour extracted from image via openCV

Tags: image-processing, statistics, errorbar, quantization, canny-operator

I am using image processing with openCV to measure the deflection of an object due to some external factor.

I extract the position by locating the outermost corner, which is deflected most. And then plot the positions over time.

Due to the resolution limit the position is not perfectly exact. What size of error bars should I add to the plot? I would assume +- 1/2 px, but I am not sure and I haven't found any literature going over this.

The image is thresholded and I am using Canny to extract the edge if that's relevant.